# Can the original Xbox (not Xbox One) read data DVDs?

Tags: xbox

I have an original xbox and was wondering is, as the title states, if it can read data DVDs?

I know that it can read CDs and import songs, but can it read data DVDs and import songs that way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an Xbox to read DVD's it has to have a DVD Playback Kit. If you do not have this kit attached to your Xbox and insert a DVD, it will give you a message telling you need it.

You may also get this message if your Xbox cannot read one of your games, and it will thus sometimes register it as a DVD.

[Here is a DVD Playback Kit you can buy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005O0I9)

Comment: Oh, and as for importing music, I'm 99% sure you cannot import music using DVD's. You have to insert a music disk and then rip it off there. 

If you want, you can add music from the movie onto your computer, then burn it onto a blank disk and put it in your Xbox.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I was just wondering because all of my blank CDs are gone and I wanted to make a mix tape to load on my xbox. Oh well, I guess I will have to stick with the four CDs I do have. Thanks!